# How to achieve similar datatype

Tags: ssis, etl, business-intelligence, ssis-data-types

Goal:
Combine two column named first and lastname, from the same table A and then transfer it to column fullname in table B from a another
relational database.

Column first and lastname has the same datatype as fullname. The datatype is varchar(50) or varchar(100).

Problem:
I can't make the transaction to have the same datatype

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the type cast expression `DT_STR` in `Derived Column` transformation so that the output from Derived Column transformation is still in varchar data type.

Below shown Derived Column Transformation shows two new columns.

First new column `FullName` takes in two input columns FirstName and LastName. Concatenates the columns with a space to separate them and then type casts to DT_STR. In `(DT_STR, 100, 1252)`, 100 represents the length of the output column, 1252 represents the code page.

Second new column `FullNameNoCast` simply concatentates the two input columns FirstName and LastName. This will result in Unicode data type.

Since, you mentioned that your destination is of varchar data type. I believe that you are not type casting the new column in Derived Column transformation. That might lead to the error you are facing.

Hope that helps.

[image: Derived Column]